# Glibc requirement update for Dropbox

Tags: centos, glibc, dropbox

Dropbox recently updated their glibc requirement to version 2.19. Centos 7 has version 2.17. It seems not to be a good idea to replace glibc manually. 
Is there any other workaround?

Comment: try this https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=68585
it worked for me................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements#linux), only Fedora 21+ and Ubuntu 14.04+ are supported as they are delivered with the required versions of `glibc` and supported filesystems.

You should not be replacing `glibc` on a system unless you really know what you are doing.  You could keep the default `glibc` and compile or install a newer version in a non conflicting location, then compile Dropbox against that and try to get it working.

You could try using Docker to run Dropbox, [there are apparently a few people that have had that idea](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=dropbox) but I have no direct experience with using Dropbox that way.

Comment: Using Docker worked for me. Install docker (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/), Then follow https://hub.docker.com/r/janeczku/dropbox/ and/or https://valh.io/blog/Dockerize-Dropbox-on-Linux